# Simplest example of a function that transforms according to $SU(2)$ and not $U(2)$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a vector:

$$
\mathbf{v}:=\pmatrix{a+ib \\ c+id}
$$

I define $f(\mathbf{v})$ as folows:

$$
f(\mathbf{v}):=\mathbf{v}^*\mathbf{v}
$$

where $\mathbf{v}^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $\mathbf{v}$.

---

The group of linear transformations which leaves $f$ invariant is the $U(2)$ group:

$$
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{v}) = f(U\mathbf{v}) \implies f(U\mathbf{v}):&=(U\mathbf{v})^*(U\mathbf{v})\\
&=\mathbf{v}^*U^*U\mathbf{v}\\
&\implies U^*U=I
\end{align}
$$

---

I am interested in a similar short proof but for a function that is invariant with respect to $SU(2)$. What addition to $f$ must occur to further restrict the det to 1? Then I am also interested in another possibly more complicated example in which the function is invariant to $SU(2)$ but **variant** to $U(2)$.

Comment: There's no meaningful difference between those two questions. If the first question isn't intended to imply that the function varies under $U(2)$, you could just use the $f$ in your example, which is invariant under $SU(2)$ (since it's invariant under $U(2)\supset SU(2)$).

Comment: @joriki can you provide a function $g(\mathbf{u})$ that is invariant with $SU(2)$ but not $U(2)$?

Comment: Why are you repeating the question in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Captain Lama already stated, you cannot do that in $\mathbb C^2$. But you can in $\mathbb C^3$: Just have $U$ act in the usual manner on the first two components, and multiply the third component by the determinant. That is, use the (reducible) representation $U\oplus\det(U)$. $SU(2)$ will keep the third component invariant, while $U(2)$ won't.

So if
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}a+ib\\c+id\\e+if\end{pmatrix}$$
then a function that's invariant under $SU(2)$ but not under $U(2)$ in this representation would e.g. be
$$f(v)=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e+if$$

Comment: How do I construct $f(v)$ in terms of $v$? For instance, as $f(v)=v^* M v$. What are the values of the 3x3 matrix $M$ such that $v^*Mv$ is $f(v)$?

Comment: Can I write: $f(v)=v^*\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}v+\pmatrix{0&0&1}\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}v$? I am looking for a definition of $f(v)$ written up in terms of $v,v^*$ that allows me to eliminate $U$ after the replacement $v\to Uv$ iff $U$ is SU(2).

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay: You can omit the matrix in the second term: $f(v)=v^*\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}v+\pmatrix{0&0&1}v$

Comment: So I have $f(Uv)=(Uv)^* M (Uv) + \pmatrix{0&0&1}Uv=v^*U^* M Uv + \pmatrix{0&0&1}Uv$. Since $M$ is diagonal, then I can rewrite as: $f(v)=v^*M U^* Uv + \pmatrix{0&0&1}Uv$. 
This gives me $U^* U=1$ which is $U(2)$, and $\pmatrix{0&0&1}U=\pmatrix{0&0&1}$. 
Why is $\pmatrix{0&0&1}U=\pmatrix{0&0&1}$ associated with $SU(2)$?

Comment: From the constraint $\pmatrix{0&0&1}U=\pmatrix{0&0&1}$ I get $U=\pmatrix{a&b&0\\c&d&0\\0&0&1}$. I do not see how to get $SU(2)$.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay: The representation used is $U\oplus\det U=\pmatrix{a&b&0\\c&d&0\\0&0&ad-bc}$. The constraint therefore gives $ad-bc=1$.

Comment: Very clever! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, there is no such function, because $U(2)$ and $SU(2)$ have the same orbits in $\mathbb{C}^2$: if two vectors $x,y\in \mathbb{C}^2$ have the same norm, then there is a $A\in SU(2)$ such that $Ax=y$.

So any function which is $SU(2)$-invariant has to be $U(2)$-invariant.